# Go: Not able to write to a file

Tags: go

Permission of file: `-rw-r--r--`

I changed the permissions to `-rw-rw--rw--` but it still doesn't work. I want to understand why this code is not working:

The function creates a file. But the function does not write anything to the file. I also don't get any error.

```golang
newfileCreate, err := os.Create("brainnew.txt")
newfile, err := os.Open(newfileCreate.Name())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
defer newfile.Close()
newfile.WriteString("sdsds sds")

// I tried writing bytes but it that also doesn't work!
```

But, if I try this code, it works!

```golang
str := "example-text"
data := []byte(str)
ioutil.WriteFile("data.txt", data, 0644)
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? Nothing written to the file? No file is created?

Comment: @Schwern excuse me. I have corrected the description of the question.

Comment: Always, really _always_: Read the documentation of each function, method and the package you are using. Guessing just leads to bugs.

Comment: @Volker Yes, I do, I read the documentation. My problem is that I don't speak English well. I read the documentation first in my own language, then I read it in English. But I agree with you. I try, I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `os.Open`. If you check the documentation for this functions it says:

```
// Open opens the named file for reading. If successful, methods on
// the returned file can be used for reading; the associated file
// descriptor has mode O_RDONLY.
// If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.
```

This means it opens file in read-only mode. If you would check the error of `newfile.WriteString()`. Then you would know, that nothing was written due to read-only mode.

Comment: yes, ths. i get error. ```os.Open``` return error ```write brainnew.txt: bad file descriptor```